# What is difference between JPA ,EJB3 and hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

i have worked on ejb3 using JPA provider of hibernate and now working on hibernate.
but iam confused that what is the difference between these technologies because jpa,hibernate and ejb3 i did not find such difference.
Can any body please explain the main features or what are the major differences between both of them

Comment: Really ?! Closed because it's not a real question ?! As long as it ends with a `?`, then it's a question and deserves an answer. If it sounds so noob to you, well it doesn't sound so to more than 900 people as of writing this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Persistence has been "broken out" of "EJB3 Core", and a new standard
>   formed, the Java Persistence API (JPA). JPA uses the
>   `javax.persistence` package, and was first specified in a separate
>   document within the EJB3 spec JSR 220, but was later moved to its own
>   spec JSR 317. Significantly, `javax.persistence` will not require an
>   EJB container, and thus will work within a Java SE environment.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Data_Objects#JDO_vs._EJB3_vs._JPA

Other explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API#Related_Technologies

Hibernate is an implementation of the JPA spec.

Comment: what are the technology wise differences means what are the features? sory my english is not so good.

Comment: Hibernate is *not* the "reference implementation" of JPA. EclipseLink is for JPA2 and TopLink was for JPA1. A reference implementation is simply a demonstration that the spec is implementable, nothing more.

Comment: @DataNucleus, thanks for correcting me. Updated the answer accordingly.